# How to get value from select option and not the contents - PHP

Tags: php, forms

I am pretty new to PHP and have looked for a solution for what I'd have thought would be a common question but I can't find the answer. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

So I have a form with a selector and various options:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="main-home-form" action="trip_search_process.php" method="post">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select location:</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="location_selector" name="location">
            <option value="default">I Don't Mind...</option>
            <option value="africa">Africa</option>
            <option value="asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="aus_nz">Australia &amp; New Zealand</option>
            <option value="europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="north_america">North America</option>
            <option value="south_america">South America</option>
         </select>
```

When this form is submitted, I have this PHP code which extracts the location selected:

```
$location_passed = $_POST["location"];
```

However, what is passed is the contents of the 'option'. What I would like is the value. I.e. for this 'option':

```
<option value="aus_nz">Australia &amp; New Zealand</option>
```

I currently get 'Austraia & New Zealand', whereas I want aus_nz

Is this possible? Or am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: If you’re not getting `aus_nz` from simply posting the form, this is not a PHP problem, because the error must be in your frontend which PHP has nothing to do with. Maybe you have some JavaScript magic active which posts the element’s content rather than the value.

Comment: I suppose you have some javascript that processes data before submitting or submits form. Because passing `aus_nz` is the default behaviour of `<select>`.

Comment: How is this form submitted as I see no submit button, are u perhaps using ajax to submit?

Comment: Hi - I just cut out the submit button from the code. It is there and looks like this:

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-xl js-scroll-trigger">Submit</button>

Comment: The value attribute specifies the value to be sent to a server when a form is submitted. I am not really sure about what you want to get and what you currently get. Try this, and try to compare to your problem: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_option_value

Comment: @Takit Isy - Yes, that demo is the behaviour I am looking for.

Although it's a shame it doesn't show the contents of the /action_page.php script so I can't compare to what I have currently

Comment: what you do with value?

Comment: Hi, There is no error in your HTML code, as old comments, you have done something with javascript/JQuery, post your source code with javascript code

Answer (score 0):

```
 <?php


    if(isset($_POST['re'])){



      if($_POST['location'] == 'default'){

       // error
         echo '<p>make a selection</p>';

      }else{

         $val = $_POST['location'];

            echo '<p> selected value; '.$val.'</p>';
      }

 }

?>

 <form class="form-horizontal" id="main-home-form" action="" method="post">
 <div class="form-group">
      <label>Select location:</label>
         <select class="form-control" id="location_selector" name="location">
            <option value="default">I Dont Mind...</option>
            <option value="africa">Africa</option>
            <option value="asia">Asia</option>
            <option value="aus_nz">Australia &amp; New Zealand</option>
            <option value="europe">Europe</option>
            <option value="north_america">North America</option>
            <option value="south_america">South America</option>
         </select><br>
         <input type="submit" name="re" id="re" value="value.">
       </div>
         </form>
```

the above code will give the value of the selected option.
Put the php code to your action page `trip_search_process.php`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
echo $value = $_POST["make"];
echo $text = $_POST["make_text"];

}
?>
<form method=post>
<select name='make' onchange="setTextField(this)">
<option value = '' > Please Select Value </option>
<option value = '5'> Text 5 </option>
<option value = '7'> Text 7 </option>
<option value = '9'> Text 9 </option>
</select>
<br/>
<input type=submit name=submit>

<input id="make_text" type = "hidden" name = "make_text" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setTextField(ddl) {
        document.getElementById('make_text').value = ddl.options[ddl.selectedIndex].text;
    }
</script>
</form>
```